Getting partial template types from nested templates
Give a series of nested template structs, I'd like to be able to extract the outer most template and "assign" it in a template using statement.
ie:
struct s0 { };

template<typename T>
struct s1 { };

template<typename T>
struct s2 { };

template<typename T>
using outer = ?????

Such that I can do:
outer<s1<s0>><int> //would be s1<int>
outer<s2<s1<s0>>><int> //would be s1<int>

I've got close by template member variable in a template struct, but I can't then "assign" that to a single using statement as it requires two levels of template statement.
Thanks in advance

I assume that outer<s2<s1<s0>>><int> //would be s1<int> is a typo and s2<int> is expected.

You can create your traits with partial specialization.
Usage is not outer<s1<s0>><int> but outer<s1<s0>, int>.
Unsure of what you want for outer<s2<s1<s0>>, int>.
So, if you want s2<int>, you might do:
template <typename T, typename Inner>
struct outer_impl;

template <template <typename> class C, typename T, typename Inner>
struct outer_impl<C<T>, Inner>
{
    using type  = C<Inner>;
};

template <typename T, typename Inner>
using outer = typename outer_impl<T, Inner>::type;

Demo
Or, if you want s2<s1<int>>, you might do:
template <typename T, typename Inner>
struct outermost_impl
{
    using type = Inner;
};

template <template <typename> class C, typename T, typename Inner>
struct outermost_impl<C<T>, Inner>
{
    using type  = C<typename outermost_impl<T, Inner>::type>;
};

template <typename T, typename Inner>
using outermost = typename outermost_impl<T, Inner>::type;

Demo

Thanks, I think it's not quite what I am after, but I am not sure what C++ supports what I want and this is close enough. Cheers.

If it is the syntax, clearly, C++ is limited to have custom syntax. If you want the traits to give you another type (and I misinterpret your requirement), then I think C++ can handle that.
